# How to restrict access to a NuGet feed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I created a NuGet Server in order to host our proprietary packages.

How can I restrict access to the NuGet server in order to allow only trusted people to download our DLL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy authentication was added in NuGet v1.4. We are building on this to support authenticated repositories in NuGet v1.5.

In the meantime, you can either restrict access by IP as suggested in the other answer. You can also create a customer route handler that allow you to create "custom" URLs for each user that embeds their authentication token. This is how DevExpress currently does it.

See http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/258457 for more info.

Comment: How do I configure it? The link didn't helped much

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's an easy way to do this right now. There's a post in the Nuget issue tracker about adding support for things like HTTP Authentication:

Issue: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/366

Discussion: http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/237995

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. 
Eventually I found an easy workaround. Simply restricting the Nuget server website access by IP address do the trick.

If someone is interested here's how to:
[This link provides a step to step tutorial](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/ipSecurity)
Moreover, make sure to mark the "Access for unspecified clients" to Deny in the "Edit Feature Settings..." dialog